# How do I display 20000 rows of data more quickly?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb

I am using datatables jquery to display the table with nodejs to make a query to the database. It is currently taking 18s to display 20000 rows of data

when i directly query the database it takes less then a second to display the data.

Comment: Why do you need to display all 20K rows in one go? I think you should display 5 or 10 and use pagination (server-side)

Comment: Who on earth wants to look at all that data on screen at once? As mentioned above, paginate it, for the user's sake as well as for performance

Comment: The end decision on your approach shouldn't be posted in the question, it should be indicated by an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even if it is possible to show 20K records in a grid, your user will definitely not be interested to see all of these at one go. Rather show a small set of data in the UI grid and provide search, sort and pagination options.

Go for both server-side (NodeJS) and client-side (jQuery) pagination. Fetch data from the database one page at a time and let the client request one page at a time. Make the page size configurable.

If server-side performance (especially database query) is not a concern then fetch all 20K data at one go. Reduces complexity at server side by avoiding pagination. However, still at client-side implement pagination to avoid rendering issue and to improve usability. Note that, by fetching all data at one go memory consumption of both server and client-side processes will increase.

If it works today well, it will definitely break if there is a possibility that your data grows over time. If not and you still want to fetch all 20K records and display at one go, then go ahead, good luck :)

Comment: Ok thanks for all the feedback sorry if the question wasnt asked properly. I already do have pagination on the frontend with the datatables library, so i am not displaying 20,000 rows of data at one go to the user. 
The issue we had was that we did a console.log(20 000rows) and didnt remove it after developing.
However it is still taking about 2-3s just to load the first page of 50rows.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data?

Rather than display 20K rows of details, summarize the data and show no more than a screenful of data.  You could do this with some kind of graph.  Or summarizing the data.  Or...

And you could have links on the consolidated data for those who need to drill down to the details.

This seems to be a UI issue.